# How to remove the group average/min/max from all rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, average

Given this data (but obviously many more rows):

```
group   value
  1      2.5
  1      3.5
  2      4.5
  2      5.5
```

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"group": [1, 1, 2, 2], "value": [2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]})
```

**How could we easily remove the group average/min/max?**

When removing the groupby result from the rows you'd get `NaN`s because of the mismatched index:

```
In [2]: df.value - df.groupby("group")["value"].mean()
Out[2]: 
0    NaN
1    0.5
2   -0.5
3    NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for repeat aggregate values per groups:

```
print(df.value - df.groupby("group")["value"].transform('mean'))
0   -0.5
1    0.5
2   -0.5
3    0.5
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know that's what transform is for!